Fuzzy Number Line
I'm trying to create a command that generates a number line for an arithmetic progression.
For example \SNL{10}{5}{9} generates a number line with the first value of 10, common difference of 5 and contains 9 numbers.
The challenge is that the number line is fuzzy and produces an error message that I can't understand. Any ideas? Thanks heaps :)
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand{\SCNL}[3]{\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.07]
\draw[latex-latex] (0.5,0) -- (#3+0.5,0) ; %edit here for the axis
\foreach \x in  {1,...,#3} % edit here for the vertical lines
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \z in {1,...,#3} {
\foreach \y [evaluate=\y using {int(\z*#2-#2+#1}] in {1,...,#3} % edit here for the numbers
\draw[shift={(\z,0)}] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\y$};}
\end{tikzpicture}\end{center}}


\begin{document}


\SCNL{10}{5}{9}

\end{document}


The center environment caused the message, and it isn't useful when the page "calculates its layout itself" ... Rather, it creates a new page with every tikzpicture environment, see screenshot.
I put % at the end of each line as a precaution: else unwanted spaces can be inserted at the lines end, thought TikZ may ignore it ... you never know.
I also put some space around each drawing as a suffestion.

\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}


\newcommand{\SCNL}[3]{
%\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale = 1.07]
\draw[latex-latex] (0.5,0) -- (#3+0.5,0);%edit here for the axis
\foreach \x in  {1,...,#3}% edit here for the vertical lines
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);%
\foreach \z in {1,...,#3} {%
    \foreach \y [evaluate=\y using {int(\z*#2-#2+#1}] in {1,...,#3}% edit here for the numbers
    \draw[shift={(\z,0)}] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\y$};%#
    }%
\end{tikzpicture}%
%\end{center}
}

\begin{document}
    \SCNL{10}{5}{9}
    
    \SCNL{-1}{3}{5} 

\end{document}


I just worked out how to remove the fuzz. Thanks MS-SPO for the assistance with the error message. Here's the new code:
\newcommand{\SCNL}[3]{
% \begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 1.2]
\draw[latex-latex] (0.5,0) -- (#3+0.5,0) ; %edit here for the axis
\foreach \x in  {1,...,#3} % edit here for the vertical lines
\draw[shift={(\x,0)},color=black] (0pt,3pt) -- (0pt,-3pt);
\foreach \z in {1,...,#3} {
% \foreach \y [evaluate=\y using {int(\z*#2-#2+#1}] in {1,...,#3} % edit here for the numbers
\draw[shift={(\z,0)}] (0pt,0pt) -- (0pt,-3pt) node[below] {$\fpeval{\z*#2-#2+#1}$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
% \end{center}
}


Fine. // Can you add a screenshot? Just wondering, why you want to scale …

It’s for a beamer slide, the easiest way to make it look centred without using \begin{center} etc is to stretch it out

Understand. // You could also include the .pdf via package graphicx, see fist code in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/721206/245790 . Then you are more flexible, both by using center and e.g. by width for the grahic pdf.
